# What is the angle of depression from the top of the tower to a cell phone user who is $5$ horizontal miles away and $400\text{ ft}$ above sea level?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, word-problem

I am having trouble solving this word problem:

> A cellular tower that is $150\text{ ft}$ is placed on top of a mountain that is $1200\text{ ft}$ above sea level. What is the angle of depression from the top of the tower to a cell phone user who is $5$ horizontal miles away and $400$ feet above sea level?

Here is my attempt:

- opposite side = $5$ miles = $26400\text{ ft}$
- adjacent side = $950\text{ ft}$

so $$\tan(?) = \frac{26400\text{ ft}} { 950\text{ ft}},$$ and $\arctan$ should give us the angle.

$$\arctan\frac{26400\text{ ft}}{950\text{ ft}} = 87.94^\circ.$$
 This angle  is the one with mountain and a slope to the head of the user.
Thus an angle of depression as it is an angle formed between the horizontal line and that slope
which is equal to $90^\circ-87.94^\circ = 2.06^\circ$.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sketch of the problem I made, did I interpret it wrong?
[image: Sketch of problem]

Comment: Notice that your answer and the text's answer sum to 90 degrees.  The text wants a different, but related, angle from the one you found.

Comment: So that would be the angle of elevation though, not the angle of depression, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think 2.06 degrees is a reasonable description of how depressed the cell phone user's position is from the horizontal line at the top of the cell tower.  Your method is absolutely sound: just subtract your result from 90 degrees to get the desired angle. The 87.94 degree angle doesn't measure how elevated anything is, so I wouldn't use the term "angle of elevation" for it, myself.

Comment: I quote from www.mathwords.com because I am not a native English speaker: "Angle of Depression

The angle below horizontal that an observer must look to see an object that is lower than the observer." http://www.mathwords.com/a/angle_depression.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *angle of elevation* refers to the angle above the *horizontal*. The *angle of depression* refers to the angle below the horizontal. By the equality of alternate angles, the angle of elevation of the tower top from the cell phone user equals the angle of depression of the cell phone user from the tower top.

The angle labelled in the picture is measured from the *vertical*, not the horizontal, and so it is neither of these angles.