# What is the angle of depression at which Chris is looking?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, word-problem

Finding angle of depression but I don't have idea of what I should mark as hypotenuse or opposite? Please help!

So, here is the question:

> Chris is standing on the top of the cliff of 70 m and sees a ocean 180 m from where he is standing. What is the angle of depression  at which he is looking?

Comment: This may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34186/find-the-angle-of-depression

Comment: you mind showing what you tried and how you understand the problem?

Answer (score 2):

**HUGE HINT**:

[image: HINT]

> the angle between the horizontal and the observer's line of sight is called the angle of depression

**Diagram with hint as requested**

[image]

Hopefully, that helps :)

Comment: I suppose this answers the literal question "What is the angle of depression?". :)

Comment: Haha yup! I think that's what the OP wants, otherwise with information provided you can't actually find the real value.

Comment: No, ok can u please make a diagram of this question for explaining by putting values please?????

Comment: @lopiz Sure, but you have only provided one value, which is height.

Comment: @gekkostate oh yeah now i have provided it ... U can read the question again :)

Comment: @lopiz Does that help? You can now easily find the angle.

Comment: @gekkostate ohh thank u so much and yeah this really helps!!!

Comment: @lopiz Anytime! I'm not sure if you have gone through the FAQ or not but just generally speaking, when you are happy with an answer, you can either upvote the answer (you need 15 rep for this) or you can click the checkmark beside the answer or do both. When you click the checkmark, you are essentially closing a loop which signifies that the question has been resolved.