# Finding angle of depression?

Tags: trigonometry

The question is that a boy standing on the top of a staircase 33m high while looking at a oatch of grass on the ground 50 m away from him.What is the anglre from where he was looking at. Please draw diagram.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you drawn the diagram?  Since it's trigonometry, did you find a relevant right triangle?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859732/finding-angle-of-depression Perhaps instead of putting your focus on solving **one** particular exercise, you should put your efforts into understanding the idea behind the solutions, so you can apply it to all these problems.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have a lot of these questions `:)` Instead of drawing the diagram for you, I will teach you how to draw the diagram. Let's split the question into two parts:

(1). a boy standing on the top of a staircase 33m high

When you see the word "high" it means "height" so draw a line straight up and imagine the boy standing on top of the line, in this case a stair case.

(2). while looking at a oatch of grass on the ground 50 m away from him.

Now that the boy is on top of a staircase, he is looking at an oatch(?) $50$m away so draw a straight line which connects to our height and ...

We're done!

The angle between the straight line and the height is the angle of depression! Good luck!